# What are alternatives to `main` elements in HTML?

Tags: html, tags

An HTML document is not supposed to have more than one `main` element.

I have got an old webpage which does not adhere to that rule (which was only made part of the W3C validation recently), and therefore I want to rewrite the HTML code without breaking too many things. It is roughly structured as follows:

```
<main> Some part of the content </main>
<main> More of the content </main>
<main> The rest of my content </main>
```

What are the alternatives to using the `main` element that do not require rewriting too much of the code?

Comment: Nowadays, few people use tags such as `nav`, `main`, `header`, `footer`, etc. These tags are no longer completely relevant. And there is a good and versatile replacement for these tags - `div`.

Comment: You can replace every single `<main>` with `<div>`. There is no difference.

Comment: @Spectric: I actually tried to replace every `main` with a `div` in my html and css files. It seems my browswer (firefox) treats them differently still.

Comment: @shuhalo That's interesting. `<main>` and `<div>` are both just tags with styling `display:block`